# Xamarin BindableProperty Value Precedence

Tags: xamarin

[WPF has this nice page with 11! rules for Value Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#dependency-properties-might-be-set-in-multiple-places)

Xamarin lacks this documentation, and apparently it differs from WPF.

What i've found so far:

(In WPF "Local Value" overrides almost everything else.)

Not so in Xamarin, where i identified this (partial) order:

1. VisualElement.Triggers
2. Style.Triggers
3. Local Value
4. Style Setter

So:

**How's the complete Value precedence in Xamarin?**

Comment: I don't find any document about BindableProperty value precedence, you can open one thread to feedback this question at github.

Comment: Created an issue: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13968

Comment: Please wait a minute, when the team sees your question, it will update immediately